# Degree of $y=1+dy/dx+1/2!(dy/dx)^{2}+1/3!(dy/dx)^{3}+......$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

$y=1+dy/dx+1/2!(dy/dx)^{2}+1/3!(dy/dx)^{3}+......$

I tried to solve it this way

put $dy/dx=t $ now our equation becomes
$y=1+t+1/2!t^{2}+1/3!t^{3}+.......$
which is just the Taylor expansion for $e^{t}$
so $y=e^{t} $

taking natural log both sides

$\log(y)=t $
$\log(y)=dy/dx ,$ so degree is 1 with order 1 but some sources say that the degree is not defined, any reason why is that the case?

Comment: Notice that $\exp(d/dx) = \mathrm{id} + d/dx + \cdots$ where the first is the **identity operator**, so if you want to take this approach, your equation is rather $2y-1 = \exp(d/dx)(y)$, i.e. $y$ is in the kernel of $D = \exp(d/dx) - 2\mathrm{id} + 1$.